# SQL Server Reporting Services - Report Expressions Execution

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Say I have the following expression:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Year,-1,Today())
```

Is there a SQL Server web service endpoint that'll allow me to pass in an expression and return the result of the executed expression? I looked through the endpoints listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/methods/report-server-web-service-endpoints?view=sql-server-2017) but couldn't find one.

Or is there another way to evaluate this expression?

Comment: Why don't you run the expression through the report you are working on. It has an expression engine built in.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the expression?

Comment: The provided report viewer is inadequate for our needs. So I've been tasked with writing a report viewer that re-uses the RDL. I have RDL schema from Microsoft but now I'm stuck trying to evaluate what looks like VBA expressions. I'm simply trying to evaluate the expression at runtime. So if I pass in the above expression I'd like something to evaluate it and return 8/24/2017.

Comment: "Report Viewer" is a control that can either be embedded in a Windows application's form or a web application's web form (or a SharePoint page). These controls display reports that are rendered by a Report Server. This server is the one that evaluates such expressions (which are VB.NET + some functions unique to SSRS). It seems to me that you are trying to re-invent the Report Server. If so, then good luck, but if there's no Microsoft Reporting Services server that needs to understand your RDLs, why don't you replace all SSRS-expressions by something that your code can easily evaluate?

Comment: No, I'm not trying to re-invent the Report Server; I'm trying to implement a lite version of the Report Viewer. The current Report Viewer doesn't work in Chrome or FireFox AND requires WebForms. I'm trying to abstract those requirements away by simply reading the parameters; providing them, click generate and using one of the SOAP endpoints, generate the report. Also, I thought the expressions where VBA and not VB.NET?

Comment: When replying to a comment on your own posts on SO, please "mention" the user, otherwise the user (me, in this case) won't receive a notification. VBA is used in Microsoft Office products. I still don't get why your code needs to evaluate such expressions when letting the Report Server render the report (using the *Execution Endpoint*).

Answer (score 0):

I've found another way to evaluate the expression using VB.net (This assumes that @Wolfgang Kais is correct about VB.net use instead of VBA)

Here is the code snippet:

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace VbStringCompiler
{
internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program();
    }

    private const string CRLF = "\r\n";

    private Program()
    {
        var vbCodeProvider = new VBCodeProvider();

        var compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters();
        compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll");
        compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        compilerParameters.CompilerOptions = "/t:library";
        compilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = true;

        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        stringBuilder.Append("Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic" + CRLF);
        stringBuilder.Append("Imports System" + CRLF + CRLF);

        stringBuilder.Append("Namespace Evaluate" + CRLF);
        stringBuilder.Append("Class RunTime" + CRLF);
        stringBuilder.Append("Public Function Run() As Object" + CRLF);

        // insert code to return
        stringBuilder.Append("Return DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, -1, Today())" + CRLF);

        stringBuilder.Append("End Function" + CRLF);
        stringBuilder.Append("End Class" + CRLF);
        stringBuilder.Append("End Namespace" + CRLF);

        try
        {
            var compilerResults =
                vbCodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParameters, stringBuilder.ToString());
            if (compilerResults.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (CompilerError compilerError in compilerResults.Errors)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine(compilerError.ToString());
                }

                return;
            }

            var instance = compilerResults.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("Evaluate.RunTime");
            var methodInfo = instance.GetType().GetMethod("Run");
            var methodReturn = methodInfo.Invoke(instance, null);

            Console.WriteLine(methodReturn);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
}
```